# command/app to compare epub files

Tags: command-line, file-comparison, epub

Is there any easy way to compare the first line/text of a epub file using command line or an app in Linux?

Details: I have 15 different epub files, each with over 10 "chapters", I'd like to compare the first few words of each chapter to see if there's a duplicate chapter. It seems most of compare commands in Linux are for text comparison, unfortunately I'm not expert in Linux.

Currently I'm using `Sigil` to do the comparison, which is time consuming, I'd prefer to use command line or an app to do it, if possible.

Comment: From a quick google, it seems ePub is a variant of XML, which means (a) it is technically text, although not simple to parse, and (b) there are tools available to make it simpler to access.

Comment: They are not just XMLs, it's a load of files packed into a ZIP archive.

Comment: The best way to go around this would be to export them to TXT files and compare them e.g. using `diff -u`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/102458/how-can-i-convert-epub-files-to-plain-text

Comment: Thanks you all for the feedback. @ArtemS.Tashkinov, there are several epub 2 txt converter, which one in your opinion is the most complete? I've found pandoc, not sure if this one I should be using.

Comment: Never used them, so it's up to you to figure it out.